# Scrape the times when users like my Facebook page posts

Tags: php, python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I found [this Facebook scraper on GitHub](https://github.com/precognox-admin/FBscraper) which scrapes for every post like a Like_ID ( The ID of a like ), person_hash_id ( The hashed ID of the liker ), and post_id( The ID of the liked post ).

However, I'd also like to scrape **when** each and every like on my Facebook page happened.

That is, if John Doe liked Post X at **17h GMT**, I also want to scrape this data.

Is there any way to determine ( or at least guesstimate ) when a post was liked from the Like ID?

Is there any other approach to this? Any help ( in any programming language ) will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Via [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=&version=v2.10), you can see all the fields you can access.
I liked a comment on a dummy group to show you all the information a like provides : it seems you can't.

I believe the right thing to do would be to check every day, or every hour, for each and every like, and have a personnal *likeDatabase*. There, you will know when it has been posted.

[image: likes]

Answer (score 0):

Graph API doesn't allow you to parse the time of the like, I think your best option is to generate a date and time and perform continual requests, for example every 10 mins or 1 hour ... etc, and assign a date and time each time you parse this data, it would look something like this:

```
while True:
    #request Graph API for some data
    parse_time = datetime.utcnow() #parse time and date in UTC tz (since Graph API uses UTC) at the time of request
    #here you should create new table 'post_like_count' this table will contain 3 columns: post_id, likes_count, parse_date
    time.sleep(60*10) #sleep for 10 mins in order not to exceed Graph API limited number of requests
```

Comment: Are you sure a five minutes lag is enough for me not to get banned for running this 24/7 ?

Comment: I think the limits reset per hour, you have to make your calculations since it depends on the number of posts you are going to monitor.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting this link gives you all the info needed about rate limiting on Graph API.